# (How) can I get `read var` to add the literal \b (backspace) to var?

Tags: bash, read

For example, the user types `foofoo\b\b\bbar`, presses enter and gets a `var` equaling `foofoo\b\b\bbar` instead of `foobar`. Yes, the user loses the deletion feature so they need to use another shortcut for deletion. Or at least the other way around: normal backspace (pressing) gives them `foobar` and some modifier + backspace-key gives them literal backspaces.

Is there a way to enable `read` to accept literal backspaces?

Comment: Note that `read -r var` is not an option because I need the actual `\x08` in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script (in bash) will accept any character except

1. ^C (ASCII 03 ETX )
2. ^J (ASCII 0A LF  )
3. ^M (ASCII 0D CR  )
4. ^Z (ASCII 1A SUB )
5. ^\ (ASCII 1C FS  )

including all other control characters:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -srn1 a ;do
    [[ "${a+x$a}" = "x" ]] && break
    var=$var$(printf '%s' "$a")
    printf '%s' "$a"
done
printf '\n%s\n' "$var"
```

Type the backspaces as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>.

Replace:

```
printf '\n%s\n' "$var"
```

with:

```
printf '%s' "$var" | od -An -tx1
```

To actually "see" the byte values.

Comment: Simply beautiful.

Comment: And most of those are because the terminal intercepts them, you could change the terminal settings to not interrupt on `^C`, for example. But you'll have to decide if that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to enter a character verbatim:

```
bash-4.2$ read foo
abc^Hfoo
bash-4.2$ printf "%s\n" "$foo" | od -c
0000000   a   b   c  \b   f   o   o  \n
0000010
bash-4.2$ printf "%q\n" "$foo"
$'abc\bfoo'
```

The `^H` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, which should be the same depending on terminal settings).

Comment: This gives me an `\x7f`.

Comment: @glarry then that's what backspace is, according to your terminal. If you want a literal `\b`, your best bet would be Ctrl-v Ctrl-H, or changing your terminal settings to make backspace be seen as a Ctrl-H.

Comment: As I implied or said, it is preferable for the backspace key to be... actually involved. At least behind a modifier. `Ctrl`+`v` is a good tip though.

Comment: @glarry if your terminal doesn't actually send a `\b` when a backspace is pressed, there's nothing bash can do. Either you take whatever the terminal sends for backspace, or if you want `\b`, you press Ctrl-H.

Comment: I had actually got that already and it made perfect sense. My vote is not for that, but for your contribution to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow the user to enter `\b` (backslash-b) for a backspace, you could replace it after the `read`:

```
read -r var
var=${var//\\b/$'\b'}
```

If you want the user to be able to hit backspace without using `Ctrl-V`, you could temporarily unset the terminal's erase character. You probably need to replace `^?`/`\x7f` with `^H`/`\x08` afterwards.

```
stty_saved=$(stty -g)
stty erase ""
read var
var=${var//$'\x7f'/$'\b'}
stty "$stty_saved"
```

The backspace still prints as `^?`, as with `Ctrl-V`.

(If, instead, you want backspaces to remove characters on-screen, but still have the backspace and the removed characters saved, you'll probably have to implement it manually.)